# Web API comments for methods taking complex types?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, comments

I have a Web Api ApiController with an action method that has structured comments that are supposed to show up on the help page.

The action is a Put that supposed to take a single [FromBody] argument that is an array of POCO objects.

```
/// <summary>
/// An acknowledgement (positive or negative) for a sent ticket
/// </summary>
public class AckNak
{
    /// <summary>jobid of the ticket that was sent</summary>
    public string jobid { get; set; }
    /// <summary>True if the ticket was successfully received, false otherwise</summary>
        public bool ack { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Put acknowledgements (positive or negative) for tickets received
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ackNaks">An array of AckNak objects</param>
[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage Put([FromBody] AckNak[] ackNaks)
{
    return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

With the above, I see the appropriate entries in the generated XML file, but I do not see the comments in on the help page. I see the method, the the summary comments do not appear.

If I replace the type of the argument with string, the comments show up on the help page correctly.

```
/// <summary>
/// An acknowledgement (positive or negative) for a sent ticket
/// </summary>
public class AckNak
{
    /// <summary>jobid of the ticket that was sent</summary>
    public string jobid { get; set; }
    /// <summary>True if the ticket was successfully received, false otherwise</summary>
        public bool ack { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Put acknowledgements (positive or negative) for tickets received
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ackNaks">An array of AckNak objects</param>
[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage Put([FromBody] string ackNaks)
{
    return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Ideas?

Comment: why are you passing like `AckNak[] ackNaks` ? try with `AckNak ackNaks`

Comment: I'm passing a collection of AckNaks, not just one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with trying to pass an array instead of a collection.

This works:

```
[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage Put([FromBody] IEnumerable<AckNak> ackNaks)
{
    return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Or, rather, this makes the doc comments work. The method itself worked either way.